# Split tuple into variable using Python

Tags: python

I have the following tuple

`res = [('fdetail',), ('fdetail1',)]`

I want to have it in two variables using Python

`var1 = fdetail`

`var2 = fdetail1`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you've got a `list` of one-`tuple`s, you'll need to do a nested unpack:

```
(var1,), (var2,) = res
```